# Restart system after doing a custom action in wix

Tags: wix

I have a requirement to execute a script and after perform it I want to restart the system. In my custom action project, I added a checking for executing the corresponding scripts. I want to restart the system when I execute the one script. This script executed only when certain conditions are satisfied only. 
Please guide me for resolving this issue.

Regards,
George

Comment: Would [ForceReboot](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/forcereboot.html) be suitable?

Comment: If we add 'ForceReboot', it will restart every installation/uninstallation sequence. I want it to reboot when certain conditions success. When I used the below solution, its worked.

Comment: If it helps, "Inner Text (xs:string)
Text node specifies the condition of the action."

Comment: sample code snippet please, if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created another custom action dll for doing the restart operation after performing a certain condition level passed. Then called this custom action in InstallExecuteSequence after installation.

Its working fine as I expected level.

Thank you all.